# Try to append the buttons to the current slide to navigate between them in slick.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

Here's my problem.

I'm using slick for creating slides on my website. It is pretty neat and essentially you can create a lot of different slides with fair customization.

The only problem is that I want to put my button to navigate between slide inside the current slide and not inside the main wrap slide, to create a better user experience and to make the navigation responsive, so when you will resize the viewport the buttons will stay stick to the center image (or current image, which is the same because they have the same class).

Here's my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    nextArrow: '<button class="slick-n"><</button>',
    prevArrow: '<button class="slick-p">></button>',
    appendArrows: ('.slider').next()
  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 5px;
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
  opacity: .2;
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.slick-n {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 48%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slick-p {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 48%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: black;
}

.slick-active {
  opacity: .5;
}

.slick-current {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}

.variable .slick-slide {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div><img src="img/main-carousel.jpg"></div>
  <div class="variable"><img src="img/carousel2.jpg"></div>
  <div class="variable"><img src="img/main-carousel.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using scss instead of css and jquery.

The first thing to notice is that this approach won't work because it will append my buttons to the right div but the arrow will work only in the second slide for some reason.

I tried to do something different before, I created a function and I called back within the slide object but it didn't work either:

```
$(function() {
  $('.slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    nextArrow: '<button class="slick-n"><</button>',
    prevArrow: '<button class="slick-p">></button>',
    appendArrows: myfunction()
  });
  function myfunction() {
    $('.slick-current').addClass('.other-class')
  }
});
```

But for some reason, it won't make me access that element. I tried many other approaches but essentially, I was never able to access the element .slick-current or .slick-center, the script always fails silently.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Have you tried to use css to put the buttons inside the image?

Comment: Yes but they won't be responsive though.. I mean I can use a lot of breakpoints but it won't be the same..

Comment: There are a few mistakes here. Firstly, you're not escaping the angled brackets (`>`, `<`) in your `nextArrow` and `prevArrow` values - it should be escaped as `&gt;` and `&lt;`. Secondly, valid `appendArrows` values, according to the docs, are `Selector, htmlString, Array, Element, jQuery object` - you're using a function with no return value (i.e. `undefined`). If you want the arrows to always be on either side of the main carousel image, just use `position: absolute;` and `left: 0;` / `right: 0;`.